# Select (dplyr) throws object error in user-defined function calls?

Tags: r

I'm trying to define a function which I can use to do a statistical test on multiple parts of my overall dataset without manually typing out multiple lines of the same code.

My original function looks like this;

```
#Mann-Whitney test for non-normal continuous variables
MW_fn = function (var) {
wilcox.test(x = df %>% filter(Diagnosis == "Control") %>% select(var) %>% pull(), y = df %>% filter(Diagnosis == "Schizophrenia") %>% select(var) %>% pull())}
```

But it throws a "object not found" error when I run it.

When I run the code outside of the user defined function with one variable (cesdhs) it runs fine and gives the result below, which looks fine..

```
wilcox.test(x = df %>% filter(Diagnosis == "Control") %>% select(cesdhs) %>% pull(), y = df %>% filter(Diagnosis == "Schizophrenia") %>% select(cesdhs) %>% pull())
```

Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  df %>% filter(Diagnosis == "Control") %>% select(cesdhs) %>% pull() and df %>% filter(Diagnosis == "Schizophrenia") %>% select(cesdhs) %>% pull()
W = 6356.5, p-value = 9.003e-09
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

Testing a few different things it seems to come down to this:

```
test_fn = function (var) {
df %>% select(var) 
}
```

which throws the error even though the variable is there in the data-frame.

Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your functions with the `iris`-dataset.
And as long as `var` is defined in quotation marks, your function works fine.

Problematic part of the function:

```
test_fn = function(var) {
  iris %>% select(var) 
}

test_fn("Species")


> test_fn("Species")
       Species
1       setosa
2       setosa
3       setosa
4       setosa
5       setosa
...
```

Full function:

```
MW_fn = function (var) {
  wilcox.test(x = iris %>% filter(Species == "versicolor") %>% select(var) %>% pull(), 
              y = iris %>% filter(Species == "virginica") %>% select(var) %>% pull())
}

MW_fn("Sepal.Length")



>   Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  iris %>% filter(Species == "versicolor") %>% select(var) %>%  and iris %>% filter(Species == "virginica") %>% select(var) %>% pull()    pull() and iris %>% filter(Species == "virginica") %>% select(var) %>% pull()
W = 526, p-value = 5.869e-07
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

If no quotation marks are used, the "object not found" error appears.

```
MW_fn(Sepal.Length)

#  Error: object 'Sepal.Length' not found
```

Comment: OMG, I think I had tried every possible combination of quotation marks apart from that one! Thank you!!